# Deploy Multi Module Maven Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloud

I have a multi module maven spring project, how can I deploy it on AWS or any other cloud platform? I googled a lot but can't seem to figure it out. I saw the AWS Beanstalk tutorial, they've uploaded a single jar file (which wasn't a multi module project), in my case since there are different modules i'm getting different jar files. What to do, kinda confused.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a big one.  There are many variables that would determine the "best" way to deploy your application. There is not going to be a single good answer to this question given only the provided information.  Much more information would be required to make any sort of narrow choice of methods.  That sort of question is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  With that said, a very common and general solution would be to use Docker to construct your app as one or more containers that you then deploy to AWS ECS.  Even if you've made this choice, there are still many variables.

Comment: The comment above is true but if you provide some details, I could try to help you. i.e: I'm using git/nexus, then all I need is a script to run at boot of my ec2 instance and download the latest package. It's a way to achieve it.

Comment: I am trying with docker as @CryptoFool mentioned, btw thanks for the idea. The structure of the project is something like this,
I have core, controller, service, repository and model as modules
-> repositories has the dependency of model module
-> service has the dependency of the repository module
-> controller has the dependency of service module
-> core is the main module which holds the main class
When doing mvn clean install the jar files are being successfully generated. How to deploy this kind of a structure?